# row_number is not unique for duplicate records

Tags: sql, window-functions, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to find the latest update of a particular row from a bunch of rows per uuid.
For that we use `row_number()` over a partition as shown below,

```
"row_number"() OVER (
    PARTITION BY "uuid"
    ORDER BY "uuid" ASC,
        "status"."sequence" DESC,
        "modifiedon" DESC
) "row_id_ranked",
```

After this, anything other than 'row_id_ranked = 1' are discarded. But when a retry/re-transmission happens, `"status"."sequence"`  and `"modifiedon"` will be exactly same. This creates mutiple rows with `row_id_ranked=1`. Making it difficult to remove them.
As per my understanding per the [documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html), the `row_number` should be a unique value. But in case of these duplicates, it clearly is not.

> row_number() → bigint#
>
> Returns a unique, sequential number for each row, starting with one,
> according to the ordering of rows within the window partition.

How do I de-duplicate in this case?

Comment: The easiest fix here would be to add a third sort level to `ROW_NUMBER`.  Is doing this possible?

Comment: since every piece of info in the row is same, (since it is a re-transmit), this will yield the same result, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there does not exist some third column beyond the status sequence and modified on date to break a potential tie, and also assuming you don't care which single record gets retained, you may use `RANDOM()` here:

```sql
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uuid
                   ORDER BY "status"."sequence" DESC, modifiedon DESC, RANDOM())
    AS row_id_ranked
```

Comment: Thanks for the 'tie-breaker', I started using 'RANDOM()' in other places too where it was difficult to do tie-breaking with existing data.

Answer (score 1):

If you use "Partition by uuid" in the "over" clause of row number you will get a row 1 for each distinct uuid. That is you have partitioned your data by uuid and the numbering will restart for each partition, as in the definition you have posted.
I think that you just want to use order by, which will return 1 row number 1.

```
"row_number"() OVER (
    ORDER BY "uuid" ASC,
        "status"."sequence" DESC,
        "modifiedon" DESC
) "row_id_ranked",
```

Comment: In fact, the requirement was to get one latest row per uuid. Hence the 'partition by'.